# Smoothness of eigenvectors at semisimple double-zero eigenvalue

Tags: analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Recently I have been considering the solvability of some linear systems, and after some transformations, it amounts to the problem below.

Suppose that a parameter-dependent matrix $J_\alpha$: $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, always has a double-zero eigenvalue
with geometric multiplicity two for every $\alpha$ in a neighborhood of
$\alpha=0$.

This means for every $\alpha$ in that neighborhood, $J_\alpha$ always has
linearly independent eigenvectors $v_1(\alpha), v_2(\alpha)\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

The question is: if $J_\alpha$ is $C^r$ smooth in $\alpha$, can we always
choose a smooth eigenvector $v(\alpha)$ associated with the zero eigenvalue?
And, how smooth can $v(\alpha)$ can be, also $C^r$?

I intuitively believe this is true, but do not know how to prove it.
Please help.